# Significado de "comprar 'a pulmón'"

Tags: expresiones, significado, economía

Hoy me he encontrado con [un artículo periodístico](https://www.expansion.com/empresas/inmobiliario/2020/07/07/5f036b4c468aeb351c8b45ca.html) cuya cabecera decía:

> el vehículo inversor del empresario gallego apenas tiene deuda ya que **compra 'a pulmón'** gracias a la gran liquidez de la que dispone el grupo por los dividendos millonarios procedentes de Inditex.

[image]

Esta expresión me ha llamado la atención porque no sabía si este uso de "a pulmón" era una variante desconocida para mi o estaba mal usado en el artículo. Yo conocía por supuesto la expresión "a pleno/todo pulmón", documentada en el DLE

> [a pleno pulmón, o a todo pulmón](https://dle.rae.es/pulm%C3%B3n)

> 1. locs. advs. Con toda la fuerza y potencia posibles. Cantar, gritar, respirar a pleno pulmón.

Lo curioso es que es la única locución documentada en esa entrada y la versión usada en el artículo no es ni siquiera "a *pleno/todo* pulmón", sino "a pulmón a secas".

Antes de consultar el DLE habría pensado, leyendo el artículo, que la expresión era asimilar a
"pagar a [tocateja](https://dle.rae.es/tocateja?m=form)" o expresiones similares que aluden a pagar en metálico, ya que me parece entender de esa cabecera (el artículo no lo he leído porque es para subscriptores) que esa ventaja competitiva que le hace no tener deuda al grupo inversor de Ortega es el tener dinero en efectivo (y no necesitar endeudarse) antes que que tener "fuerza y potencia" (porque estoy seguro de que a ciertos niveles, se puede conseguir "fuerza y potencia" de compra con otros mecanismos que no implican tener el dinero disponible).

El otro sentido que le puedo ver tiene que ver con el submarinismo: sumergirse a pulmón es aguantar la respiración sin ayuda de artefactos. Sería entonces como la locución "a pelo":

> 4. loc. adv. coloq. Sin protección, ayuda o defensa de cualquier tipo. Se enfrentó a la situación [a pelo.](https://dle.rae.es/pelo?m=form)

Así pues, el uso de "a pulmón" en "comprar **a pulmón**" ¿hace referencia a **potencia** o capacidad como en "a *todo/pleno* pulmón", hace referencia a la **liquidez** como en "a tocateja", a hacerlo **sin ayudas** de ningún tipo (que en este caso sería la deuda o necesidad e financiación) como en "a palo" o es otra cosa? ¿Puede alguien aportar para la explicación otros ejemplos de "comprar (o hacer algo) 'a pulmón'"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es un concepto usado en temas económicos para referirse a realizar una compra con la liquidez propia, sin tirar de avales o deuda bancaria.

Está muy bien descrito en [5 factores externos que marcan el precio](https://www.expansion.com/blogs/quemada/2019/08/09/5-factores-externos-que-marcan-el-precio.html), en *El blog de Enrique Quemada Clariana*:

> Cuando el dinero se contrae porque a los bancos les entra miedo, apenas prestan y las empresas se ven obligadas a comprar a pulmón, **con la caja que ellos son capaces de generar**.

O bien en la noticia de El País [*Los pisos de fondos extranjeros irrumpen en el mercado*](https://elpais.com/ccaa/2018/10/21/catalunya/1540137884_175571.html):

> El director general de Amat Immobiliaris, Guifré Omedes, que ha comercializado viviendas para estos nuevos actores del mercado, reconoce su mérito al desembarcar “asumiendo riesgo, **con un capital importante** y siendo los primeros que se creyeron la recuperación”. El capital extranjero les permitió comprar suelo en 2013 y 2014, cuando aquí **no había crédito y nadie podía comprar a pulmón**.

Mirando un poco aquí y allá se ve su uso en otras noticias, como la de *El Confidencial*, octubre de 2018: [Thomas Meyer compra a pulmón el 10% de Desigual tras su pelotazo con Eurazeo](https://www.elconfidencial.com/empresas/2018-10-30/thomar-meyer-compra-pulmon-10-desigual_1636078/).

---

La explicación tiene todo el sentido que tú planteas de paralelismo con el submarinismo (o el montañismo): cuando uno hace un esfuerzo *a pulmón* es porque no usa mecanismos artificiales para respirar, en forma de bombonas de oxígeno y similares.

Por otra parte, no creo que sea pagar *a tocateja*, pues raramente las compras a nivel empresarial se realizan inmediatamente. Supongo que simplemente se acuerdan unos plazos para los pagos y, en este caso, el comprador va depositando el dinero que saca única y exclusivamente de su caja.

Comment: Gracias. Genial respuesta, especialmente la parte final distinguiendo las connotaciones de *"a pulmón"* frente a *"a tocateja"*. Qué raro entonces que la locución "a pulmón" no se incluya en la entrada de "Pulmón", ya que tiene significado propio que no se infiere necesariamente de las acepciones descritas (habré que decirle a Charlie que les de un toque a sus contactos de la RAE ;-P).

Comment: @Diego entiendo que es un uso nuevo y aún muy circunscrito a un contexto muy determinado. Supongo que un caso parecido sería [_a pelo_](https://dle.rae.es/pelo) que empezó a usarse para referirse a cabalgar sin silla de montar y ha ido cogiendo registros de forma vertiginosa hasta llegar a lo sexual.